# R: Alias command called with system()

Tags: r, bash

In my `~/.bash_profile` file I put this `alias` command:

```
which mvsync
alias mvsync='rsync --remove-source-files -arvuP'
    /usr/bin/rsync
```

It works fine from the bash shell but when I call it from within R with `system` I get a command not found:

```
R
system('mvsync --help')
sh: mvsync: command not found

## Or
system('mvsync --help', intern=TRUE)
sh: mvsync: command not found
Error in system("mvsync --help", intern = TRUE) : 
  error in running command

## Or
system("bash -i -c mvsync")
bash: mvsync: command not found

[4]+  Stopped                 R
```

Other environmental variables in bash_profile are correctly recognized by R/system(). 
Any idea how/if it can be fixed?

This is the R session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0    data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] chron_2.3-45     colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.8     grid_3.1.3       gtable_0.1.2     MASS_7.3-39      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.3      reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `system('mvsync --help', intern=TRUE)`

Comment: @pacomet No luck I'm afraid (see edited post),  but thanks.

Comment: An alias is a bash-ism, not a shell-ism (sounds contradictory, I know). Try `system("bash -i -c mvsync")` (the `-i` is important to get bash to access features like aliases).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, but still not working (see edited post). By the way, I see that `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash.

Comment: @dariober, okay, my point is that using bash in a system call is not the same as using bash interactively, ergo the need for `-i`. Curious, though, since what I posted works on both of my ubuntu and windows machines. Try `-l` (login) as well (see this [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)), assuming this is a problem with *where* you are defining your alias(es).

Comment: @r2evans Ok, thanks for the pointers I'll try to play with it... (`-l` doesn't work either...!)

Comment: Only exported environmental variables pass to child shells.  Put the alias definition into the ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: @r2evans wtf are you talking about, aliases are way older than bash and functions

Comment: @izabera, perhaps I understated things: just because you have access to an alias (or function or whatever you go crazy about) in an interactive shell environment does *not* mean it is available via system calls. Some docs/apps incorrectly refer to these as shell-commands (despite not always using the bourne shell, c-shell, or whatever), so I made a distinction. Your argument makes no sense though: who cares which is older? The OP is using `bash` and making incorrect assumptions about how aliases are made available in other contexts.

Comment: @dariober, did you try the use of *both* `-i` and `-l`? That is, `system("bash -l -i -c mvsync")`? Each individually is insufficient.

Comment: Using `bash -l -i -c` still no good!

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm running into the same issue: recreating a bash login from R's `system`.

Answer (score 4):

Your shell is probably not a login shell: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

--login may work but it may be better to put your alias in .bashrc which will be executed even if it is not a login shell

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by using `system2` and using bash in interactive mode, i.e. by adding `-i`, or as login shell (`-l`) depending on where you add your aliases.

Example when your aliases are assigned in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
system2('/bin/bash', args = c('-ic', shQuote('mvsync --help')))
```

from `man bash` we learn that

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive  login  shell,  or  as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` [`-l`] option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> [...]
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started [`-i`], bash reads and executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option will force bash  to  read and execute commands from file instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shell sessions.

You'll need to either run

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Inside your system call, e.g.

```
system('bash -l',input=c("shopt -s expand_aliases","mvsync --help"))
```

Or define the `BASH_ENV` environmental variable and add it to that file.