# Create a shell alias that R can recognise

Tags: r

I have an alias (actually, a function) on my .bashrc but R doesn't seem to recognise it.

```bash
fun() {
  echo "Hello"
}
```

which runs correctly when I log in via ssh (it's a remote server). However, if I run `system("fun")`, I get

```
sh: 1: fun: not found
Warning message:
In system("fun") : error in running command
```

From a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305973/r-alias-command-called-with-system) I can get `system("bash -i -c fun")` to work, although with a weird warning/message

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (27173): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
Hello
```

However, this doesn't apply to my case, because I'm running external code so I cannot modify the `system()` call. I need `system("command")` to use the `command` command that I defined.

BTW, this is all running on Linux (Debian in the remote server, but I also tried on my machine running elementary OS with the same result).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi `shell` exists but only on Windows versions of R, not macos or linux. (Honestly, I don't like `system`, `system2`, or `shell`, based on base-R's blatant use of `paste` to combine the command and arguments; anything with an embedded space nullifies the entire utility of it, if it can even execute. The `processx` package is much more robust in this regard, in addition to better handling of async/background processes.)