# R can't find icc to compile packages

Tags: r, bash, archlinux, icc

I've compiled `R-mkl` package in Arch Linux using the Intel OneAPI compilers. But I cannot install packages from inside R, since it cannot find `icc`. The path in order to bash find the executables is defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/intel64/"
```

When I try to compile a package, it says it cannot find icc:

```
> install.packages("lazyeval")
Installing package into ‘/home/juliano/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
tentando a URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lazyeval_0.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 83482 bytes (81 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 81 KB

* installing *source* package ‘lazyeval’ ...
** package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
icc -std=gnu11 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O3 -fPIC -m64 -march=native -fp-model precise -fp-model source -I/opt/intel/mkl/include  -c expr.c -o expr.o
/bin/sh: linha 1: icc: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:169: expr.o] Erro 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lazyeval’
* removing ‘/home/juliano/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/lazyeval’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lazyeval’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPvcR2C/downloaded_packages’
```

How I do instruct R to read `/etc/bash.bashrc` or define the path to the compilers manually?

I have also tried to define the path in a file in `/etc/profile.d`, without success.

Comment: Note: it works when I create a symlink to the compiler in `/bin`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305973/r-alias-command-called-with-system maybe this will help -

Comment: @user12256545 I couldn't check that, since now I'm facing an additional problem. R is trying to compile packages with `gcc`, instead of `icc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sourcing setvars.sh script to initiate the OneAPI environment.

source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh

As you said, it will work if you create a symlink to the /bin.

Refer to the below link to get more details on usage of R with Intel OneAPI
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/using-onemkl-with-r.html

Comment: My OneAPI has no `setvars.sh`. But if it had it, where should I supposed to put this `source`? R appears not reading `/etc/profiles.d/*`.